# Need to find the unique entries in a dataframe column

Tags: python

[New to python] 
I have a data frame column of 22 million entries. I have to find all the unique entries.  How can I accomplish this task by using parallel programming in python?

I have pcap files, I extracted Source IPs and Destination IPs as textfile and then converted to dataframe then merged into a single column which has 22 million entries and Now I want to find Unique IP addresses of all the entries.

I am thinking of partitioning the data and load chunks of data to the process by multiprocessing and updating the global variable. Will this one help in optimizing the running time?

Comment: hmm on repl.it which has a pretty weak processor this operation takes about 0.15 seconds https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/RevolvingNanoMacro why are you trying to parallelize it?

Comment: @JoranBeasley sir, I want all the list of unique values in the column, Here I am thinking of using multiprocessing and divide the single linear job into multiple linear jobs and scheduling them on different processors simultaneously updating the shared global variable. And also may I know what Unique function is using in the back end to find all the unique entries?

Comment: `df[df[col].unique()]` will select all unique rows

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df["Column Name"].nunique()
```

Comment: Manish Chaudhary, I have already tried it. I want to do it using multiprocessing.

Comment: have you already loaded your data into dataframe or you're starting from scratch. you must specify some more information like data source you're loading your data from to get help or suggestion